# Having trouble in testing authorization policy in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm having trouble testing authorization policy, it's showing a risky test, I don't know how to fix this. This is a newly installed laravel 5.5

```
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 99 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Risky: 1.
```

This is my test code:

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $this->get('/home')
        ->assertStatus(403);
}
```

When I use `dd($this->get('/home')->getContent());`, I get an error something like this..

```
file_get_contents([internal]): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in Frame.php line 122
```

This is my home controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('create', User::class);
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

This is my `UserPolicy.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Additional:
I saw this: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/risky-tests.html
And I tried setting all of this to `false`, but the risky is still showing.

Comment: Tag `phpunit`...

Comment: What is in your home.blade.php?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort, doesn't matter, even if I comment out `return view('home');` or I use `return 'test;`, the output is still the same.

Comment: @TamilvananN, what do you mean tag `phpunit`? The `phpunit` command is working fine, if I create another test its working. I think the problem is the code `$this->authorize('create', User::class);`.

Comment: What if you add the `--stderr` flag to phpunit?

Comment: @ThomasMoors, same output, problem still persists

Comment: At the moment your passing a string to the authorize method, could you try `$this->authorize('create', User::make());` e.g. passing a User Model to the policy.

Comment: @Remul, the output is still the same, as you may know, I'm reading the Laravel documentation thoroughly, and my synthax in `authorize` method is correct because I don't require a model in this case. Refer to this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-controller-helpers under "Actions That Don't Require Models"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage to solve my problem by myself, I just ran `composer update`.

Seems that the problem is in the package `filp/whoops` v2.3.0, that's causing an exception. They managed to fix this in v2.3.1.